# Intranet Hosted and deployed Chrome Web Apps?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, group-policy, gpo

Our district is starting to use Chrome as a secondary browser. We currently customize a users experience with chrome via the GPO ADM files. However one thing we would like to do is have pre-installed webapps in the Chrome app page. These are simple apps that link to intranet applications and utilities that we use throughout the district.

I know you can force install apps from the chrome web store via the GPO ADM settings, but I don't know if I can apply this process to files hosted in our network.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Google's docs](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/188453) it doesn't have to be on the store, but it does have to be hosted somewhere accessible to the box:

> **Pre-installing via group policy**
>
> Using policy to deploy an extension or Chrome web app is the easiest
> and most scalable method. This is the recommended method for pushing
> extensions,**as it does not require the CRX file to be on the machine. It must simply be available at a given URL.**
>
> To use this method, set the policy to "force install" the extension,
> as described [here](http://dev.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#ExtensionInstallForcelist).

Comment: The part about this that I don't fully understand is how I link to the extension. Is it as simple as putting the CRX file on a network share and dumping that share address in to the GPO settings? Because it doesn't really make that clear in the information on the site.

Comment: Are you able to get the extension ID of your extensions?  You should be passing that with the update URL to the machine.  The Update URL should be one of these: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/autoupdate.html

Comment: I get no extension ID because it doesn't show up in my extensions list. It shows up in my apps list. Its basically a simple web link to an internal address. Not sure how to get it to actually show up in the list.